# CentOS MariaDB Enterprise Edition Remote Access

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos

I am working on cleansing and optimizing the WordPress performance because of the overload. So I am moving database as a server and the webserver separately. I have installed MariaDB 10.6 enterprise edition in CentOS 7.9 and created the database.

I can access over SSH, but when I do connect from the public IP and the port, it doesn't working.

Anyone having Idea about the remote access of MariaDB Enterprise database.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is "doesn't working" exactly (include exact error message)? Are the webserver and database in the same local network in the server infrastructure? Is there a private IP address available between the two.?

Comment: There is no private ip shared between them. Both webserver and dbserver are different VM